# Why do old nuclear reactors leak radiation in the coolant?

Tags: nuclear-physics, nuclear-engineering

I started working back what causes nuclear power plants to become unprofitable and came across the news that Exelon Energy had to get Illinois to subsidize their Quad Cities power plant to avoid shutting it down due to clean water regulations. After reading the NRC status update on Quad Cities, I found they have elevated radioisotopes in their coolant water compared to newer plants.

My question is this:

Why do older nuclear power plants leak radiation in their coolant? Doesn't that mean the fuel elements have become damaged, or does the radioactivity come from activated components dissolving into the coolant?

Comment: A link to the source you found would be a helpful starting point.

Comment: This appears to be a question about engineering rather than physics.

Answer (score 2):

Due to heavy neutron bombardment, the elements in the stainless steel used in the coolant loop plumbing , pumps, valves, etc. become progressively more radioactive with time. The daughter elements from the decay cascade of those activated elements are not necessarily as corrosion-resistant as the original elements (iron, nickel, chrome, vanadium, molybdenum, etc.) were, and so these will dissolve into the water and contaminate it.